# React Native don't show image when I fetch image file path from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native

I have a database with a courses table.

[image]

I want to show the image through the image path saved in the field image column.

In my react native app I have a component that lists Carts where cart's images are saved in disk

Like: `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Rectangle_2.png`. Then I put the path in image column.

**CartList.js**

```
import Carts from './../Cart';
const Item = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <Carts
      name={item.name}
      price={item.price}
      offPrice={item.offPrice}
      image={item.image}
    />
  );
};
class CartList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.requestAPI();
  }
  requestAPI = () => {
    const apiURL = 'http://myApi/api/courses';
    fetch(apiURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          data: responseJson,
        });
      });
  };

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <Item item={item} />;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyEtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I access to image path through props in Cart.

**Cart.js**

```
const Cart = (props) => {
  return (
    <View
      <Image
        style={{
          width: '40%',
          height: 100,
        }}
        source={{uri:props.image}}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default Cart;
```

when I run the app, then  I get this error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried to log your src ?, also each image should have width and height as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Well, to start, your file points to a file on a C drive. Your phone has a separate file system of it's own, so it can't access files you have on your server's C drive. What you can do instead is make your endpoint return the bytes of the image instead of path to the image

Comment: I didn't try to log my src. each image has width and height but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have incorrect image path, please check that your remote path of image is correct, I think the image path is misleading.